# How to install ruby1.9.3 on Mac OS 10.7.5?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, ruby-1.9.3

I have installed XCode 4.5 and command line tools. Then I install the latest RVM. When I try to install ruby1.9.3, I got the following errors. It seems like the C compiler can't be executed.

chris$ `rvm install ruby`

No binary rubies available for: downloads/ruby-1.9.3-p327.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/chris/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml to /Users/chris/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4
Configuring yaml in /Users/chris/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --prefix=/Users/chris/.rvm/usr', please read /Users/chris/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/chris/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Installing yaml to /Users/chris/.rvm/usr
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p327, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #extracted to /Users/chris/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #configuring
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327 --with-opt-dir=/Users/chris/.rvm/usr', please read /Users/chris/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.

The content in the log file:

2012-12-17 21:46:44] env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327 --with-opt-dir=/Users/chris/.rvm/usr
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in /Users/chris/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
Seeconfig.log' for more details

Then I have tried to install the GCC on the https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer .  The error still show up.

I have also tried to change the cmd to `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang`, but got same errors.

Do I need to set up some environment variable? Or do I miss something?

Comment: I recommend installing either MacPorts (http://www.macports.org/) or Homebrew (http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) and let it take care of the drudgery

Comment: I second @sbooth on homebrew http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2011/07/30/installing-rails-on-os-x-lion-with-homebrew-rvm-and-mysql/

Comment: according to gcc docs, you cant use gcc+xcode CT. Uninstall both and then install gcc and try to do whatever you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the XCode command-line tools installed? I also use homebrew, but have been able to build ruby-1.9.3 from rvm on Lion and (now) Mountain Lion.

Comment: Can you compile a simple C program, eg:

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    puts ("hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}